# How to suspend variable assignment with boost::bind or boost::lambda?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to suspend a void() function that sets a stack variable to true. How can I do this?

```
bool flag = false;
boost::function<void()> f = ...;
f();
assert(flag);
```

This is, obviously, toy code that demonstrates the problem. My attempt at this, using `bind`, was `bind<void>(_1 = constant(true), flag);`, but this yields a compilation error.

Comment: Pardon me, but I am experiencing high levels of agitation due to your inability to use my prior help.  Alas, I shall not help you further if, once taught to fish, you still seek the fish monger.

Comment: @Noah: Get over yourself. He is using Boost.Lambda, even if he does not say so in the question body, so telling him to do so isn't particularly useful.

Comment: I don't use Boost's functions library often, but perhaps you don't want lambdas at all. Just write a traditional function that sets a parameter to true, then bind that parameter. `void F(int& x) { x = true; } boost::function f = bind(F, flag);`?

Comment: @Dennis I had thought about that, but I figured there must be some lambda-y way to do it. I like anonymous functions.

Comment: @Noah I think you misunderstood my confusion; the documented examples for nullary lambdas aren't particularly clear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `boost::bind`, you'd need to make a function that sets a boolean to true, so you can bind to it:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>

void make_true(bool& b)
{
    b = true;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    bool flag = false;

    // without ref, calls with value of flag at the time of binding
    // (and therefore would call make_true with a copy of flag, not flag)
    function<void()> f = bind(make_true, ref(flag)); 

    f();
    assert(flag);
}
```

However, lambda's will help here. Lambda's are like bind, except they make functions too, so keep your code localized (no need for some external function). You'd do something like this:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace boost::lambda;

    bool flag = false;

    function<void()> f = (var(flag) = true);

    f();
    assert(flag);
}
```

Same idea, except `bind` and `make_true` has been replaced with a lambda.

Comment: Aaaah, so I was barking down the wrong path, trying to wrap a lambda in `bind`. This is much more elegant, like I imagined it should be. Thanks!